# flutter bad state in intitializing bloc code

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:shop_cart/model/shop.dart';
import 'package:shop_cart/repository/shop_data_repository.dart';

part 'shop_event.dart';
part 'shop_state.dart';

class ShopBloc extends Bloc<ShopEvent, ShopState> {
  ShopDataProvider shopDataProvider = ShopDataProvider();

  ShopBloc() : super(ShopInitial()) {
    add(ShopPageInitializedEvent());
  }

  @override
  Stream<ShopState> mapEventToState(ShopEvent event) async* {
    if (event is ShopPageInitializedEvent) {
      ShopData shopData = await shopDataProvider.getShopItems();
      ShopData cartData = await shopDataProvider.geCartItems();
      yield ShopPageLoadedState(shopData: shopData, cartData: cartData);
    }
    if (event is ItemAddingCartEvent) {
      ShopData cartData = await shopDataProvider.geCartItems();
      yield ItemAddingCartState(cartItems: event.cartItems, cartData: cartData);
    }
    if (event is ItemAddedCartEvent) {
      yield ItemAddedCartState(cartItems: event.cartItems);
    }
    if (event is ItemDeleteCartEvent) {
      yield ItemDeletingCartState(cartItems: event.cartItems);
    }
  }
}
```

The error thrown is

```
Bad state: add(ShopPageInitializedEvent) was called without a registered event handler.
Make sure to register a handler via on<ShopPageInitializedEvent>((event, emit) {...})
```

i am shopping cart also the library used is depriciated plz change the code according to new library and also correct the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code, for each event add on method

```
class ShopBloc extends Bloc<ShopEvent, ShopState> {
      ShopDataProvider shopDataProvider = ShopDataProvider();
    
      ShopBloc() : super(ShopInitial()) {
        on<ShopPageInitializedEvent>((event, emit) async {
          ShopData shopData = await shopDataProvider.getShopItems();
          ShopData cartData = await shopDataProvider.geCartItems();
          emit(ShopPageLoadedState(shopData: shopData, cartData: cartData));
        });

        on<ItemAddingCartEvent>((event, emit) async {
          ShopData cartData = await shopDataProvider.geCartItems();
          emit(ItemAddingCartState(cartItems: event.cartItems, cartData: cartData));
        });
    
        // others
      }
    }
```